# SQL NOT EXISTS does not work

Tags: sql

The following code does not seem to recognise the code in the brackets that after the NOT EXISTS statement.

```
select *
from department
where
NOT  EXISTS 
(select *
from department    
where UPPER(state) != 'VIC');
```

I have spent hours on this and can not seem to get it to work (can do using a different query but not the one above).

Comment: What result are you after? Why not just `select * from department where UPPER(state) != 'VIC'`?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work because you have at least one row in your table `department` where `UPPER(state) != 'VIC'` is true.

Work it out in your head, first execute the subquery:

```
SELECT *
FROM department
WHERE UPPER(state) != 'VIC'
```

If this returns *anything*, then your outer query looks like this, effectively:

```
SELECT *
FROM department
WHERE NOT TRUE;
```

Which means it won't return anything.

Now my followup question to you is:  What do you WANT it to do?

I suspect there's no reason to use a subquery at all.  I would suggest this as a possible alternative:

```
SELECT *
FROM department
WHERE UPPER(state) = 'VIC'
```

But since I don't know what end result you actually want, I don't know if this is appropriate.

Comment: HI Flimzy, I need to use the NOT EXSISTS  - I ahve been able to get it to work the way you suggest. I am trying to display all rows that contain 'VIC'.

Comment: Why do you think you need to use NOT EXISTS? If all you need is the rows that contain VIC, why not just look for that? `WHERE UPPER(state) = 'VIC'`.

Comment: for uni so need to demonstrate I can use it but can not get it to work at all.

Comment: it is only a part of it that I am stuck on and cant get past - all the sub queries do not seem to be returning anything

Comment: @user2967555: You need to provide much more information, then. Like, exactly what output you expect, and what you're getting instead, etc. We can't read your mind.

Answer (score 0):

Why use 2 queries? Instead you can try

```
select * from department where UPPER(state) <> 'VIC'
```